# Image Manipulation - Java

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio, jmagick

I recently developed a Java Servlet running on Tomcat7 that is supposed to accept POST of pictures from different formats (PNG, JPG, BMP). And perform the following tasks:

- Scale them down if greater than 2000px
- Cache other dimensions (if allowed)
- Run a hashing algorithm to identify similar images
- Store and cache them all as JPG

As fastest solution I rely on ImageIO that was producing a decent result before i ran into more "new" formats. There are two main issues that I can not find a working solution for:

- Progressive JPEG
- JPEG that includes EXIF metadata

I evaluated different solutions but none of them seems to solve both solutions (i will list best two):

- Apache Imaging (read EXIF, **can not read/write JPEG**, **it is slow**)
- JMagick (accept JPEG & Progressive JPEG, **do not care about EXIF**)

Has anyone of you been able to implement a solution that works with both formats?

Comment: What problems does Exif metadata and progressive JPEG cause? Normal `ImageIO` should be able to read most of them fine. My [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/) JPEG plugin adds support for more special cases and CMYK JPEG. Do you need to preserve the Exif metadata? Do you want images rotated according to Orientation tag? It's not very clear what you mean by "works with both formats"...

Comment: From what I've seen (I made it work, but it took me a week) without TwelveMonkeys ImageIO, there is no default support for any progressive JPEG, I tried many of them. Exif metadata are not identified and therefore images are read but oriented in the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, the Exif orientation is a common problem. I thought about fixing it in my plugin, but the demand was never great enough to bother implementing it. It's easy enough to just get the meta data and do the orientation change outside the plugin. Feel free to suggest it as a new feature though! But I've yet to come across many progressive JPEGs my plugin can't read. I'd be very happy if you could supply me with some files that fails on reading.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) which also uses [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) under the hood like [JMagick](https://github.com/techblue/jmagick). But instead of being a wrapper for the native libraries it uses the command line to communicate with *ImageMagick*.

*ImageMagick* has the operation `-auto-orient` which converts the image to the "correct" orientation automatically. For detailed information take a look at the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient).

### Advantages

- Very fast, especially if *ImageMagick* was compiled with optimized libraries like *libjpeg-turbo* (standard e.g. in *Debian* distro)
- Supports more *ImageMagick* operations than the *JMagick* versions included in distros like *Debian* (as of writing).

### Disadvantages

- Uses command line interface to communicate with *ImageMagick* which may be not allowed due to security restrictions.

### Maven Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.im4java</groupId>
        <artifactId>im4java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Example 1 (with files)

```
        // prepare operations
        final int width = 2000;
        final double quality = 85.0;
        final IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
        op.addImage("/path/to/input/image.jpg"); // input
        op.autoOrient();
        op.resize(width);
        op.quality(quality);
        op.addImage("/path/to/output/image.jpg"); // output (rotated image @ 85% quality)

        // create and execute command
        final ConvertCmd convertCmd = new ConvertCmd();
        convertCmd.run(op);
```

### Example 2 (with input/output streams)

```
        // prepare operations
        final String outputFormat = "jpeg";
        final int width = 2000;
        final double quality = 85.0;
        final IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
        op.addImage("-"); // input: stdin
        op.autoOrient();
        op.resize(width);
        op.quality(quality);
        op.addImage(outputFormat + ":-"); // output: stdout

        // create and execute command
        final ConvertCmd convertCmd = new ConvertCmd();
        final Pipe inPipe = new Pipe(inputStreamWithOriginalImage,
                null); // no output stream, using stdin
        convertCmd.setInputProvider(inPipe);
        final Pipe outPipe = new Pipe(null, // no input stream, using stdout
                outputStreamForConvertedImage);
        convertCmd.setOutputConsumer(outPipe);
        convertCmd.run(op);
```

### Example 3 (image information)

```
        final boolean baseInfoOnly = true;
        final Info info = new Info("/path/to/input/image.jpg",
                baseInfoOnly);
        System.out.println("Geometry: " + info.getImageGeometry());
```

### Performance

You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42022982/5223047) for performance optimizations (but beware that there was a `-colorspace rgb` and an unnecessary, because not supported for JPEG images, `-coalesce` operation which both increased the processing time).

### Documentation

[Here](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html) you can find the developers's guide with more examples.